# How to evenly split traffic between two pages

Tags: php, jquery

Purely hypothetical at this point, no code yet. Trying to figure out the best way to do this. We are company "A" and we have two partners, company "B" and company "C". On a sign up form, we collect data and then pass it on to either partner "B" or parnter "C" - this part is good to go and working fine. I do this with ajax on the front end and a cURL processor on the back end so no one leaves our site and just post the data directly to the partner's form.

Unfortunately due to partner "B" and "C"'s required data the forms we post to are different and we have to have 2 separate html form files, one for each partner. The problem is that we need to do this all from one URL, not a separate one for each partner.

I would guess we would use a 'handler' page that has the specific url - http://www.example.com/parterForm.php

Then in the 'handler' page we would make the switch serve the correct content. I need a way to evenly split who we send data to. I'd like to do the switch on a very granular, MS level for example:

if the time = 0-500 ms - serve Parter B page;

if time = 501-1000ms -serve Partner C page;

all done within the 'handler' page - calling the forms as php includes?

I realize this is not a specific code question and I aplogize, this is something I've never done before and am trying to figure out how to do this. I'm a Creative Director btw who codes, no other resource avail.
thanks.

Comment: Is there any data that is filed into the form that may be used to trigger which partner receives what, instead of using a time value?

Comment: It would be easy to round-robin them b,c,b,c,etc But to work out the latency between your site and the user will be the chore.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is substantial differences in the forms which is why I have to serve two separate forms. If it was just who to submit to that would be easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, yes, you could do that. That would work reasonably well, in fact. The important thing is to make sure the form goes to the right partner. You could use `$_SESSION` for that, or check which fields were sent and deduce from that which partner was chosen.

For example:

```
if( fmod(microtime(),1) < 0.5) include("forms/partner1.php");
else include("forms/partner2.php");
```

Then when submitted:

```
$partner1fields = array("name","email","country","dateofbirth");
$partner2fields = array("name","address","postcode","ethnicity");
// the above are examples - they should correspond to the $_POST keys you expect
// now check if they match. Array equality depends on order, so sort first
$postkeys = array_keys($_POST);
sort($postkeys);
sort($partner1fields);
sort($partner2fields);
if( $postkeys == $partner1fields) { /* submit to partner 1 */ }
elseif( $postkeys == $partner2fields) { /* submit to partner 2 */ }
else {
    echo "<p>Given keys did not match either partner</p>";
    echo "<p>POST keys: ".implode(", ",$postkeys)."</p>";
    echo "<p>Partner 1 keys: ".implode(", ",$partner1keys)."</p>";
    echo "<p>Partner 2 keys: ".implode(", ",$partner2keys)."</p>";
    echo "<p>Please report this error to the site administrator.</p>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I get the top part, that's exactly what I (think) I'm after. The second part is above me at the moment. If I serve "forms/partner1.php" it will post to a differnt curl file so I don't see the need for the bottom part - Im sure Im missing something

Comment: What the second part does is establish which form was served to the user. You need to make a list of keys (ie `name="..."` attributes) for each form. If the keys match, you can then send the cURL request accordinly. If they don't match, it will print an error message, that's the whole last part.

Comment: This is awesome. I think I can make this work - there has been one adidtional parameter to this project that throws a monkey wrench in it but I think I may possibly still be able to make it work. In the form there is a radio button and if a user selects a certain option, it now sends to a partner "D" regardless of the time. ugh.

Answer (score 0):

First, by MS I assume you mean the latency between client and server?

1. Use javascript to either load a tiny image from the server or make an ajax call that gets one char or something and time this.  For testing you'll need to do some real pings and adjust your js time to reflect the ping round trip.  For example, if the js time to load the image is 500ms but ping time is only 80ms then maybe divide by 6 for the result.  This will never be very precise as the client and the server both have processing overhead.  Make sure to echo no cache headers or past expire times with the image or ajax response.
2. Easy, if time <= 500 redirect to form A, if time > 500 redirect to form B or use ajax to load them up.